# custom MapView class not displaying map when first created

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am building an Android app that requires extending the MapView class from the google maps API v2. I have it partly working but my issue is that the map displays as a gray grid. However, if I make the keyboard appear on screen pushing the map up slightly the map displays properly.

Is there something that refreshes the mapview that I need to call that making the keyboard appear is doing by itself?

Here is the relevant source code: this is for the constructor for the class I am making that extends MapView

```
public MyMap (Context context)
    {
    super (context);        
    this.onCreate(null);
    mMap = this.getMap();

    MapsInitializer.initialize(context);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(40,-80),15));
    }
```

mMap is a member function that is a GoogleMap object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you doing all this inside a constructor instead of onCreate?

Comment: it has to be done in the constructor because it is being used in part of a program I do not have control over that calls the constructor but not the OnCreate function.